# If delegates are immutable, why can I do things like x += y?

Tags: c#, delegates, immutability

Reading *C# In Depth, 2nd edition*, section 2.1.2 on combining and removing delegates.

The subsection title states that "delegates are immutable" and that "nothing about them can be changed."  In the next paragraph, though, it talks about using constructs like

```
x += y;
```

where `x` and `y` are variables of compatible delegate types.

Didn't I just change `x`?  Or does the immutability part deal with when `x` is disposed of when I do this (i.e., immediately)?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That's like doing:

```
string x = "x";
string y = "y";

x += y;
```

Strings are immutable too. The code above not changing the string *objects* - it's setting `x` to a different value.

You need to differentiate between *variables* and *objects*. If a type is immutable, that means that you can't change the data within an instance of that type after it's been constructed. You can give a *variable* of that type a different value though.

If you understand how that works with strings, exactly the same thing is true with delegates. The += actually called Delegate.Combine, so this:

```
x += y;
```

is equivalent to:

```
x = Delegate.Combine(x, y);
```

It doesn't change anything about the delegate object that `x` *previously* referred to - it just creates a *new* delegate object and assigns `x` a value which refers to that new delegate.

Comment: How about that, an answer from the guy who WROTE 'C# In Depth'

Comment: @Neil: Yes, being answered by Jon Skeet is such an exceedingly rare occurence on SO that this is a notable coincidence.

Comment: @stakx: Exactly, yes. So if you have two references to the same delegate: `x = y;` and then do `x += z; y.Invoke();` then that call to `y.Invoke()` *won't* invoke the delegate referred to by `z`.

Comment: @Sii, not often does the question arise from someone reading the book though.  That's the notable part.

Comment: @stakx: exactly. That is also why it's not a good practice to combine `string`s in a loop: with each iteration, a new string value is created, and the previous one discarded.

Comment: @Sii: LOL! +1 for both this answer as well as the question, I never thought of delegates (along with their invocation lists) as being immutable. @Jon: Sorry for deleting my previous comment. (For posthumous purposes: It basically said that I was baffled if that were true, since I had always thought invocation lists of `MulticastDelegate`s to be mutable.)

Comment: @stakx: Yes (in response to a question no longer present), which is why one should make a copy of an Event's delegate and check if the copy is `null` before invoking the copy -- rather than checking the original against `null` before invoking -- in order to avoid a race condition.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: So I first have `x` and `y` that refer to objects that contain "x" and "y".  Those objects don't change.  By doing `x += y;` a new string object containing "xy" is created, and `x` refers to that?  Then the old object that `x` used to refer to is disposed of if nothing else points to it?  Something like that? :)

Comment: @John: Sort of. No disposal going on, which is separate from garbage collection - and no garbage collection in this particular example as it uses string literals, but that's a bit of a detail :) In the delegate case the new delegate object would still have a reference to the original delegate object, or at least to the actions in its invocation list...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jon.  Very much enjoying your book.  (This is a unique place: Where else someone can ask a question about a book and have the author answer the question in *two minutes*?)

Comment: @John: I'm really glad you're enjoying it, and of course feel free to ask more questions. I can't guarantee to answer *every* question in quite that time frame, of course ;)

Comment: @Jon: Oh of course!  I understand that Stack Overflow is not SAAS (Skeet As A Service)! ;)

Answer (score 5):

You have changed `x`, but didn't change its value (i.e. the delegate it was holding).

It's the same as:

```
int num = 4;
num += 2;
```